# Is there a way to direct event hub event to the service endpoint in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

One of the ways to do this is probably to use the Function app which makes the call to the appropriate web service endpoint. But just wanted to see if there are any other effective ways to direct the event hub events to the appropriate API endpoint based on the message sent.

Comment: if you have a web api with eventhub subscriber you could directly recieve it there

Answer (score 1):

Events webhook you can use for capturing the events to the custom api endpoints. Below are the steps to enable to your custom api endpoints

[image]

[image]